# TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

i am new to aws and express app i am getting this error in pm2 does anyone know why i am getting this error

```
0|index  | TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
0|index  |     at Object.module.exports [as sign] (/home/ubuntu/newapp/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:108:58)
0|index  |     at /home/ubuntu/newapp/index.js:100:21
```

i think error is in this line does anyone know how to fix this error only in aws it work in local host with out error

```
  let payload = {
        useremail: user.email,
        _id: user._id,
      };
      let token = jwt.sign(payload, "secretKey");
```

Comment: Make sure that the `"secretKey"` argument passed to the `jwt.sign` method is a string, and not an object

Comment: What is your version of `node`?

Comment: i am realy new to backend and express app so i have diffulty in following  if a i am sure i secretKey  is the ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET in .env file ? correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Konrad i did node -v in aws and got 
v10.19.0

Comment: @Konrad in local i did the same v18.12.1 i got this

Comment: does that mean i have to upgade it?

Comment: This library requires at least [node 12](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/package.json#L57). It requires `KeyObject` class which is not available in node 10 https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-keyobject

Comment: oke i will upgare node js and try